# optimizing mysql table with 1.5m records where most are soft deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, optimization, myisam

I've got a MySQL table that has around 1.5 million records and the table size is 1.3GB

I am using a soft delete mechanism in that table, which means I've a column `deleted_at` which indicates whether the row has been deleted and when. if the record is not deleted then `deleted_at` value is `NULL`

From these 1.5 million records, only 30K are not soft deleted. that means they are accessed frequently, while the other records are barely accessed, but they are, in some cases.

So this table is heavily used and queried for the none deleted records, and sometimes for the soft deleted records.

I have a `BTREE` index type for the `deleted_at` record (with cardinality of 35K). The table becomes heavier with time and obviously it is not a scalable solution.

The table engine is `MyISAM`. most of the other tables are `InnoDB` but this table is queried heavily with `STORED PROCEDURE`, and when I changed to `InnoDB` the queries were way slower.

I am looking for a solution that will not involve hardware changes. the current hardware is sufficient for that table to have good performance, but this will not be the case once this table will grow more.

Things I thought of :

- partitioning, but I cannot use `partitions` as some of the columns are `FULL TEXT` indexed.
- split data into two tables. one for the deleted rows and one for none deleted rows which accessed and queried frequently. this change requires a lot of infrastructure changes so I am not in a hurry to do this.
- creating a new table that will sync with the original table once in 10/20min instead of splitting and will contain only the none deleted rows. that will require small infrastructure changes as well the maintenance is much easier and safe. splitting into two table could result in missing records due to queries failures, as "DELETE" operation will actually move row from one table to another, and thus requires sophisticated mechanism

What other options do I have? can I give priority to some rows in a table with MySQL? memory wise.

I've got `10.3.20-MariaDB` and 32GB of RAM

Comment: Are there certain queries that are showing significantly poor performance you could provide that might be optimized better?  Also, indexes on tables (covering indexes too) can improve.  The request on options to improve can be offered, but if the underlying structure and specific indexes and how queries are structured could be improved by other means.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  What version of MySQL?

Comment: @RickJames I've got `10.3.20-MariaDB` and 32GB of RAM

Comment: `FULLTEXT` exists for InnoDB in 10.3.  (Actually since 10.0.5)  Your table is small enough so that it should be easily cached in RAM.  So, the gross inefficiency of fetching, then discarding 98% of the desired rows should not be too bad.

Comment: @RickJames what are you implying? I've tried to use InnoDB with `FULLTEXT`. but I have this not so simply query (involves distances calculation) that performs poorly with `InnoDB`. are you saying that after splitting the tables it will make sense to move to `InnoDB`?

Comment: "distances calculation"??  That adds a big wrinkle to the Question.  What's up?

Comment: sorry if I was misleading, but I did mention the use of a heavy STORED PROCEDURE that does not perform well with `InnoDB`

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (yourtablewith1.5Mrows);  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyISAM does not cache rows, it only caches indexes. It relies on the filesystem cache for buffering rows.

So you could try to ensure at least the index is fully loaded into the cache:

1. Increase `key_buffer_size` so it's at least as large as your MyISAM indexes for this table. Use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to find out the index size.
2. If you have multiple MyISAM tables, you might need to dedicate a key cache specifically for this table. See [CACHE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cache-index.html).
3. Pre-load the index into the key cache at startup. See [LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-index.html).

You may also want to consider multi-column indexes tailored to your queries. Like if you have a query `WHERE user_id = 1234 AND deleted_at IS NULL`, you should create an index on `(user_id, deleted_at)`.

Which indexes you need depend on the queries you want to optimize.

Frankly, I would split the table so deleted rows are in a second table. That would reduce your table size by 98%, and that might make queries run quick enough that you don't need to use MyISAM anymore.

Comment: Even I would have preferred splitting data into two tables so that deleted records isolated from frequently used data. May be OP has some restriction.

Comment: They just say it would require "a lot of infrastructure changes" which I guess means other code that references the table would have to change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am considering third option: creating a new table that will sync with the original table once in 10/20min instead of splitting. that will require small infrastructure changes as well the maintenance is much easier and safe. splitting into two table could result in missing records due to queries failures, as "DELETE" operation will actually move row from one table to another, and thus requires sophisticated mechanism, what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: I'd use `pt-archiver` which is a free tool to safely copy or move data from one table to another. It's part of the Percona Toolkit. https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit

Comment: `find out the index size` you mean the column `Index_length` correct?

Comment: Yes, it corresponds to the size of the `.MYI` file in the case of a MyISAM table.